# Error importing data from textarea in dialog into google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dialog, on which there are some textarea and an Insert button to import data from the textarea into Google spreadsheet. Here is the code:

```
<td><button style="width:40%" onclick="insert();google.script.run.onEdit();">Insert</button></td>
```

Here is the html code

```
 function insert() {
        var title = document.getElementById('Qnumber').value;
        var content1 = document.getElementById('content').value;
          var content = replaceContent(content1); 
        var formula1 = document.getElementById('formula').value;
          var formula = replaceFormula(content1,formula1)
        var unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
        var option1 = document.getElementById('A').value;
        var option2 = document.getElementById('B').value;
        var option3 = document.getElementById('C').value;
        var option4 = document.getElementById('D').value;
        if (document.getElementById('formula').value !=="") {
          google.script.run.enterName1(title,content,formula,unit);
        }
        else {
          google.script.run.enterName2(title,content,option1,option2,option3,option4);
        }
        
      }
```

Here is the gs code

```
function enterName1(title,content,formula,unit) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tests');
  var title = sh.getRange(Number(title)+1,1,1,3).setFormulas([[title, '="'+content+'"', '=round('+formula+';3)'+'&" '+unit+'."']]);
}
function enterName2(title,content,option1,option2,option3,option4){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tests');
  var title = sh.getRange(Number(title)+1,1,1,3).setFormulas([[title, '="'+content+'"', '=if(column()=3;"'+option1+'";if(column()=4;"'+option2+'";if(column()=5;"'+option3+'";if(column()=6;"'+option4+'"))))']]);
}
```

When I run the program, the "enterName1" function works and the "enterName2" function does not. Can anyone help me to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the documents attached to the script, or a mock-up document without personal information. Also, according to the script only one of the two functions runs at each execution, did you run them one by one without the insert function?

Comment: Thank  Kessy and Cooper,

Comment: Thank Kessy and Cooper, I found the cause. The two variables `content` and `formula` I changed a bit to two other functions, and these functions don't match, so an error occurs. I will explain more in the answer to the question.

Comment: As mentioned below. Please see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please delete your answer and edit your question to clarify it, or if it's a new question, please open a new question.